# How to read the browser HTTP Header sent to play in a controller action?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

### Question text/background and finds

My browser sends some HTTP header (e.g. referer) to my application I'm building in the play 2.0 framework. I'm completly clueless how to read them so i can pass them on (google isn't helping).

I *think* I might need to do something mentioned here (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaInterceptors). Which resulted in:

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
   println("headers:" + request.headers.toString)
   super.onRouteRequest(request)
}
```

Which works outputting to the console. But I don't know how to pass them to a specific controller action. I could, for example, add an `if` statement and call `myAction` once it sees a specific 'route' (eg /client/view/123) or call `super.onRouteRequest(request)` otherwise. But I'd lose the functionality in my `/conf/routing`. What is the 'proper' way of doing this?

In my queste to answer that I found [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/11zbMtNI3A8/q5IuEBcIefcJ): `Http.Context.current().​request()` but using that in my controller action gave me a `[RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]`.

Another thing I found is [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/ZBLeUTo9aMk/XTzPDQZHcc8J) where Guillaume Bort replies to a, I *think* unrelated question:

```
I'm not sure what you are trying to do but:

case class CustomRequest(token: String, request: Request[AnyContent])
extends WrappedRequest(request)
case class CustomAction(f: CustomRequest => Result)
extends Action[AnyContent] {

  lazy val parser = BodyParsers.parse.anyContent

  def apply(req: Request[AnyContent]) = req match {
    case r: CustomRequest => f(r)
    case _ => sys.error("Invalid usage")
  }

}

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = CustomAction { request =>
    Ok("Token: " + request.token)
  }

}

With onRouteRequest:

  override def onRouteRequest(req: RequestHeader) = {
    super.onRouteRequest(req).map { _ match {
        case a: CustomAction => Action { (request: Request[AnyContent]) =>
          a(CustomRequest("XXX", request))
        }
        case o => o
      }
    }
  }
```

But that is a bit over my head atm (and perhaps not even an answer to my question). But if this is the way to go let me know.

### Question summarized

What would be the proper/nice way to read HTTP Headers sent by the browser in a contoller action? I only care/need the HTTP Header in a few routes.

Thanks for any pointers or nudges!

PS: 
1) I'm new to scala and play (and development on the web via rails like frameworks), so my apology for any lingo errors (do tell).
2) New to stackoverflow as well ... but it looks awsome, hope I did everything OK for my first question here!
3) I had 5 links/finds but no reputation to allow that, so narrowed my question down to the 3 interesting webfinds , sorry.

Comment: +1 too bad it appears there is no straightforward way to inject data into the Request via onRouteRequest (yes, WrappedRequest allows this, but when you need to inject a variable into the Request for every route regardless of Action, onRouteRequest sure would be a great place to do it...)

Comment: Can you please restate the question at the top of this post? Something like TL;DR I'm trying to do (blah)? It's hard to parse out what the main question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read headers using the examples [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaActions).

Essentially:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    request =>
    // your code that reads request.headers here
    Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
  }

}
```

You can change the headers in a response using this [example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaResults).

Comment: Oh wow, that easy eh?
The code example you provided didnt work, but the one in the link did! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I'll amend it so it works now I've got an IDE in front of me :)